# php trims everything after space

Tags: php, string, variables, string-concatenation

I'm really scratching my head...

I'm trying to add a class to my input and textarea fields, but whenever I do it like this:

```
$inputclass = $class." multilanginput";
```

the second part is not appended, but when I leave out the space and do it like this:

```
$inputclass = $class."multilanginput";
```

it works just fine...

i've never had this issue before, any ideas what's going wrong?

it's part of this little function:

```
function backend_dynamic_dialoginput($label,$class,$type = 'single',$lang = "none"){


if($lang == "none"){
    $lang = "";
}
else{
    $lang = "_".$lang;
}

$class = $class.$lang;
$id = "";

if($type == "singleint" || $type == "multiint"){
    $id = $class."_m";
    $inputclass = $class." multilanginput";
}else{
    $inputclass = $class;  
}


$html = "
<div style='padding-left:10px;margin-top:1px;background-color:#dddddd;padding-bottom:8px;padding-top:8px;'>
    <div style='float:left;font-size:13px;color:#5a5a5a;padding-top:6px;margin-bottom:2px;width:30%;text-align:right;padding-right:4px;' class='font_lato'>".$label."</div>
    ";

    if($type == "single" || $type == "singleint"){
        $html .= "<input type='text' value=".$inputclass." style='font-size:12px;width:60%;border:1px solid #ffffff;padding:2px;background-color:#dddddd;' class='font_din' id='".$id."' class='".$inputclass."'>";
    }
    else if($type == "multi" || $type == "multiint"){
        $html .= "<textarea style='font-size:12px;width:60%;border:1px solid #ffffff;padding:2px;background-color:#dddddd;' class='font_din' id='".$id."' class='".$inputclass."' rows=2></textarea>";
    }

    $html .= "
    ";

    if($type == "singleint" || $type == "multiint"){
    $html .= "<div style='float:right;font-size:12px;background-color:#eeeeee;margin-right:4px;' id='".$class."' class='togglefullscr font_lato'>Int.</div>";
    }


    $html .= "
    </div>";

if($type == "singleint" || $type == "multiint"){
$html .= backend_dynamic_internationaldialog($label,$class,$type);   
}

return $html;
```

}

Comment: Does it trim it only in the html context or did you print out the variable (for example before you fill $html) with echo $inputclass ?

Comment: when i do this: if(strpos($inputclass,"multilanginput")){$inputclass = "found";} the value field says "found", so the second part must be in the variable, but it does not get printed to html jquery doesn't react to the class and it does not show up in the input fields value.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your quotation marks are wrong:

`$html .= "<input type='text' value=".$inputclass."`

It has to be `$html .= "<input type='text' value='".$inputclass."'` or `$html .= "<input type='text' value=\"".$inputclass."\"`.

However, I strongly recommend using single quotes for strings:

`$html .= '<input type="text" value="'.$inputclass.'"...>';`.

Answer (score 1):

You have not put quotes around the HTML attribute.

Change the line to:

```
$html .= "<input type='text' value='".$inputclass."' style='font-size:12px;width:60%;border:1px solid #ffffff;padding:2px;background-color:#dddddd;' class='font_din' id='".$id."' class='".$inputclass."'>";
```

When you omit the quotes like this, the second class name will be treated as another property.

Problems like this can be easily avoided if you [validate your markup](http://validator.w3.org/) ;-)

Answer (score 0):

You can escape spaces using `\x20` and `\040` in php.

http://php.net/manual/en/regexp.reference.escape.php

Please see the manual